How to cope with underflow in a Windows 11 24H2 SEH
Something has changed in the way Windows 11 24H2 handles floating point exceptions -- or rather the way it recovers from them. In our Fortran system we have a Structured Exception Handler (SEH) that handles floating point underflow and forces the underflowed value to zero. This particular code is specific to Win32 and it is usually triggered as an 80-bit value is stored in a 32 or 64-bit format. Our exception handler is at least twenty years old but in Windows 11 24H2 it can no longer recover from a floating point exception.
Our current code is quite large and difficult to post, however, below is a sample that works on Windows 11 prior to 24H2 and loops forever in 24H2 - it will print 'handler' repeatedly. Does anyone know if this is a deliberate action by Microsoft or a regression (it looks like a regression)?
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "float.h"
#include "windows.h"

LONG WINAPI handler(_EXCEPTION_POINTERS * ExceptionInfo)
{
    if (ExceptionInfo->ExceptionRecord->ExceptionCode == EXCEPTION_FLT_UNDERFLOW)
    {
        puts("handler");
        // clear exception bits
        ExceptionInfo->ContextRecord->FloatSave.StatusWord &= 0x7f00;
        DWORD* p = (DWORD*)ExceptionInfo->ContextRecord->FloatSave.DataOffset;
        // store 0 (not actually needed for this test)
        if (p) *p = 0;
        return EXCEPTION_CONTINUE_EXECUTION;
    }
    return EXCEPTION_CONTINUE_SEARCH;
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR * argv[])
{
    float x, y;
    unsigned int control_word;
    int ctrl;
    short sw;
    PVOID exh = AddVectoredExceptionHandler(TRUE, handler);
    // enable underflow exception
    ctrl = _controlfp_s(&control_word, 0, 0);
    ctrl = _controlfp_s(&control_word, ~_EM_UNDERFLOW, _MCW_EM);
    x = FLT_MIN;
    y = 20;
    // create an underflow
    _asm {
        fld x
        fld y
        fdiv
        fstp x
        wait // boom
        fnstsw sw // what sw do we have
    }
    printf("Finished: %20.7e %20.7e\n", x, y);
    return 0;
}

We have tried to talk to Microsoft about this but our path has been blocked on each occasion.

This appears to be 32-bit code running in the WoW64 emulator. Do you see the same behavior when compiling for a 64-bit target?

AFAIK, how FloatSave works is undocumented, and it indeed seems to have changed (I can reproduce), so I wouldn't call that a regression. Alas, only Microsoft could tell you for sure how it all works now.

Besides, isn't this just a manual way to do what _DN_FLUSH does already? What's the specific reason you aren't calling _controlfp_s to enable flushing of denormals to zero?

@IInspectable the 64-bit system is completely different and uses a hardware flush to zero.

We aren't using _controlfp_s because although this is a Visual Studio example our 'real' system doesn't use Visual Studio or any of the crt.

When talking to Microsoft, you may be more lucky when not using undocumented stuff, this similar code (I think) seems to also behave differently under 24H2 and uses only documented calls https://pastebin.com/raw/mNeZiY4w
